# Cannot stub AWS KMS with Sinon

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, sinon, amazon-kms

Writing a nodejs AWS lambda in which one step is using AWS KMS CMK to encrypt a data key.

Trying to create unit test for the step where I get stuck. I cannot stub the AWS KMS class using Sinon. I think the problem is Sinon cannot resolute the correct type of the object. What I can do to solve the problem. Thanks.

Running the test I got type error:

```
TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property encrypt
    at Sandbox.stub (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/sandbox.js:288:19)
    at Context.<anonymous> (test/cryptoKmsCmkTest.js:20:22)
    at Context.done (test/cryptoKmsCmkTest.js:10:9)
    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:126:23)
```

Here is the test code:

```
'use strict'
const AWS = require('aws-sdk') // AWS SDK
const sinon = require('sinon')

describe('test KMS mock', function () {
    let sinonSandbox
    let result
    beforeEach(done => {
        sinonSandbox = sinon.createSandbox()
        done()
    })

    afterEach(done => {
        sinonSandbox.restore()
        done()
    })

    it('Config Create', async function () {
        process.env.AWS_CMK_ALIAS = 'cmk-key'
        sinonSandbox.stub(AWS.KMS.prototype, 'encrypt').returns({
                                                                    promise: function () {
                                                                        return Promise.resolve(result)
                                                                    }
                                                                })

    })

})
```

Comment: I would suggest try this with aws-sdk-mock (https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-mock)

Comment: Edit your post and provide the code under test

Comment: @MukeshRawat Tried aws-sdk-mock, it worked. Thanks

Comment: @slideshowp2 The test is all the code for now. Just to demonstrate Sinon cannot find AWS.KMS.encrypt in aws-sdk.